# Retagging of 7 special [untagged] questions?

Tags: support

There are like [7 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tagged with (only) the tag [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

All of them seem to be pretty special (popular), and they do not show up if you just search for questions using that tag. You need to add `is:q` in your search to have them dispayed.

As per the usage/design of this special tag, these 7 tags should be retagged somehow. However "I" do not have permission to "suggest an edit to any of them".

What can be done to get them retagged anyway? Can somebody with enough rep (moderator?) take care of retagging them?

Extra curiousity: why does one have to add that `is:q` to the search to actually see them?

FYI: after all those remaining questions got retagged, the process related to this special untagged tag will make that tag to be removed (until next time an untagged questions pops up).

Answer (score 3):

You can't. They are locked,and kept for their historical significance.

No edits are allowed, and even if you flag it, a moderator will just decline it. There is no use in editing these questions.

Comment: I think the "You can't" should be reworded to "You need sufficient rep to do so". I do understand the histrical reasons. But the way these 7 questions are currently tagged, it is somehow blocking the special process relatted to tag "untagged". That is what I believe should be resolved somehow (and is the purpose of my request/question). Unless there is a "historical reason" why any of these tags must be tagged with "untagged", which I believe is NOT the case. See my point?

Comment: No. Reputation has nothing to do with it. It is locked. Period.

Comment: why are you talking about reputation here? That has nothing to do with the question here, your answer, or any comments I think.Am I missing something? Moreover: these "locked" questions are blocking the regular process about the untagged tag . Period.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: The context you're missing is apparently your own assumption that there's some sort of rep sufficient to allow anyone to edit these questions. There isn't. No one can edit the questions (or answers), and the fact that they're [tag:untagged], while unfortunate, is not especially important.

Comment: The posts being untagged prevents gaining tag reputation on that posts.

Comment: Thanks for both previous comments (and extra context added here). If that's true, then I wonder where I can find more details about what's written in http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges, related to rep of 15 k and/or 20k ... Especially: what if somebody with at least 15K accidently (by mistake) protects a question? Is there really no way for somebody with sufficient rep to correct such mistake? FYI: looking at http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools doesn't seem to help either to find the answer to my remaining question(s) ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Protecting a question just protects it from being answered by no-rep users. Locking instead is a moderator-only action, which takes things completely out of the hands of non-mods.

Comment: @Deduplicator : interesting, thank you for teaching. About your "... takes ... out of the hands of non-mods": that sounds to me like " ... and from then on only 'mods' are the only ones who can still do something with such questions". Am I close? If so: could (and should?) a moderator then step in to retag those untagged questons? As a kind of "last resort"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Yes for everything but the last: I don't see any good tags these questions should have.

Comment: They are tagged as untagged as that is the last resort tag for moderators to use only. It's for questions that have no suitable tags as they are basically off-topic for the site but are kept due to their historical significance.

Comment: Aha, now we are cooking! So in the end, moderators are using a tag that 'nobody' should ever consider using (that is part of the tag wiki for untagged ...). From all those hundreds of tags available, there has to be at least 1 tag for each specific question, no? And if not, then just invent (+ create) whatever tag for all of them. How about tag "no-suitable-tags"? While waiting for this to happen some day, I'm going to be investigating if any existing tag might be a fit anyway ... If I find any, I just add an extra comment here ...

Comment: How about retagging the question about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake with either 'source' or 'source-code'?

Comment: No. It can't. Just leave it.