# No question should be [untagged]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request, blocklist-request, meta-tags

We currently have two questions, asked within the past year, tagged [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

"Untagged" seems suspiciously like one of those dread [Meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that we are not supposed to have on SO. In fact, it's the ultimate meta tag - it tells us literally nothing about the question except that no one could find (or could be bothered to find) something better to tag it with.

In 2015, there was a [request to retag *seven* questions tagged as "untagged"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296226/retagging-of-7-special-untagged-questions), so apparently this tag is still getting used.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

- No, it tells us literally nothing about the question except that no one could find (or could be bothered to find) something better to tag it with.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

- No, it's a [Meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

- Only that no one could be bothered to tag the question properly. That's a social issue, not a taxonomic one.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

- Yes, it means that the question has no other useful tags, but that's not helpful.

Could we retag all [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions and blacklist the tag?

Comment: When questions are migrated and no tags exist, that tag is used. That tag is also what the mod/cm burnination tool applies to questions which have no tags after removing the tag to be burninated. The tag is also currently blacklisted and cannot be added by normal users. Just retag or close/delete the questions as necessary.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the use of the tag. What Tiny Giant said. It's the default goto when tags are destroyed. It literally means what it says. The post is untagged.

Comment: The two questions currently untagged are both migrations, one is a rejected migration.

Comment: Yep and migrations.

Comment: Seems like the sensible thing to do would be to fill out the tag wiki.

Answer (score 23):

Questions become "untagged" automatically when something happens to a tag that was already on the question. Perhaps a staff member completely destroyed that tag and the question had nothing else. But more commonly, it's because it was a single-use tag that had no wiki, which will get automatically deleted by the system after a few months if it never garners any other questions.

The tag itself *is* blacklisted for all intents and purposes. You cannot add it to a question (only the system can), and you cannot edit a question without replacing it.

Comment: In this case maybe the original tags (both questions were migrated) don't exist on stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndréKool Yeah, that's another situation. Those migrations are rejected automatically if not done by a moderator on another site, but become untagged if a moderator forces it through.

Comment: @animuson why, then, would a moderator not just go ahead and tag the question? Isn't that, well, sort of sloppy moderating?

Comment: @RobertColumbia That requires the same tag existing on the source site first, which isn't always true (different sites have different tagging structures). I wouldn't recommend a moderator create an arbitrary tag before migrating just so it can be tagged at its destination.

Comment: @RobertColumbia we don't necessary know a question is untagged.