# Can the untagged followers please attend to their tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

For no particular reason I checked if we had questions that were [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Turns out we have 562 of those beauties. Probably an over-eager CM or Mod clicked some buttons to mass-remove tags without checking if that would leave many orphans (explained in the answer on [No question should be [untagged]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372558/no-question-should-be-untagged)) And after that action we didn’t clean up properly.

Can we, in the next 6 to 8 weeks, go over that list and curate the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions?

- Looks like the majority is from a Team Foundation Server tag mishap.

  - Janw found a [tfs2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2019) among the [tfs-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-2005) and [tfs-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-2015). <s>Maybe a mod that passes by can add that `-` between `tfs` and `2019`.</s> done
- I’ve retagged some that were migrations from other sites.

As always: Do all you deem necessary to the question, comments and answers, if you retag.

Seeking advice? Helping out? Join [the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217467/untagged-clean-up).

Comment: Just looking at the first/last couple of pages - they seem to be about Team Foundation Server... seems a bit coincidental...

Comment: Looks like tfs-2010 was nuked

Comment: Interesting, because other tfs tags are still fine. I wouldn't have a clue why someone would nuke tfs-2010. Sounds like a bug or accident that likely should be reverted

Comment: I would say almost _all_ are about TFS...what are the appropriate tags here? Just [tfs]? There are also [tfs-2005], [tfs-2015] and [tfs2019] (sic!), it might make sense to remove those as well, while we are at it...

Comment: ...but I agree with @ErikA, having specific tags for TFS versions isn't a bad idea, as long as these are consistently named and used.

Comment: Yeah, it is especially strange, since I merged [[tag:tfs2010]] into [[tag:tfs-2010]] in December of 2019. I would obviously not have done that if [[tag:tfs-2010]] did not exist, so it got removed some time between now and then. (This was part of a larger clean-up of TFS version-specific tags that I did. They were all intact at that time.)

Comment: @Cody was just looking at the syn. page... wonder if it's possible the merge fell over and only did the remove tag part but never actually added the tag?

Comment: It's strange that there is no edit listed in the timeline where the tag was removed. Can moderators edit tags without leaving a timeline entry?

Comment: It is suspicious that the most recent of these untagged TFS questions got posted in November 2019, but that might also just be because the 2010 version is way outdated by now and no-one asked anything about it this year

Comment: @BDL look at the screenshot in Martijn's recent answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOKqM.png

Comment: @Jon Yeah, that's possible. I can't really think of any other explanation. I doubt a CM just got a wild hair one day and went in to delete the [tfs-*] tags.

Comment: *mumble mumble something about using database transactions mumble mumble...*

Comment: Can this be undone in an automated way, or do we have to go through these 562 questions and retag them manually?

Comment: It's probably best to tag them manually. Also gives us the change to fix issues with these posts, where applicable

Comment: Ok, I would be glad to help, if I can. Should off-topic questions be sent to SOCVR, or just flag and pray?

Comment: Not all the untagged questions are for TFS.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983796/facebook-login-is-failing-sometimes-in-ios-sdk-4-38-0 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506656/how-to-transform-gdf-time-domain-to-human-readable-time-intervals.  Can a regular user like myself create an [tag:untagged] question, or is this some reserved tag?  If not, is there any way to see how the question was originally tagged before it became [tag:untagged]?

Comment: @dbc correct. that is why I said *majority* in my question. As for the adding the tag yourself to a question, I just tested that: *The 'untagged' tag is not allowed.
This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead.*

Comment: Another question: The very first question I checked is about TFS 2012, where no tag exists. Do we do this properly and create new ones?

Comment: Should we now create a new tfs-2010 tag? It's a bit inconsistent when other tfs version have version tags and 2010 doesn't.

Comment: @dbc We could probably use one of the data dumps, but if SEDE has picked it up, there's no easy way to do it. tags being removed in the way this one was is basically the equivalent of deleting and pretending it never existed. There's no way to check it using the timeline, or revision history, or any other non-frozen (read: data dumps) data assets

Comment: I don't have any problem with people creating `[tfs-*]` tags where appropriate, to match the existing pattern of [[tag:tfs-2015]] and [[tag:tfs-2005]]. But **remember all the usual caveats of version-specific tags**, namely that you shouldn't use them just because the asker happens to be using that version. The problem needs to be somehow specific to that version. Also, *always* use the "master" tag (in this case, [[tag:tfs]]), never *just* the version-specific tag. (cc @BDL)

Comment: I can't even guess the correct tag for [How to transform GDF Time Domain to human-readable time intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506656/how-to-transform-gdf-time-domain-to-human-readable-time-intervals).

Comment: @dbc Looks like [tag:java], [tag:datetime-conversion]

Comment: I'm just editing all the posts to have a [tag:tfs-20xx] tag on them.

Comment: @10Rep in the Answer we've put as guidance that also the base tag [tag:tfs] should be added.

Comment: @rene Ok, I'll go over them again.

Comment: We need to create a tfs-2011 tag. For some reason it doesn't exist.

Comment: @10Rep has that product ever existed? There was a version 11 but that was either tfs 2012 or tfs 2010

Comment: @rene See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593126/tfs-2010-modified-date-on-checked-out-files) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=tfs+2011&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS819US819&oq=tfs+2011&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.1978j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Please note that unclaimed tags may be picked up from the taggage counter but will be disposed of after 30 days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Done

No more untagged questions in the system! Thanks for everyone that chipped little bits of the workload.

#### Original

There is a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217467/untagged-clean-up) to coordinate this effort.

Guidance:

- When people create [tfs-*] tags where appropriate, do match the existing pattern of [tfs-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-2015) and [tfs-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-2005). But remember all the usual caveats of version-specific tags, namely that you shouldn't use them just because the asker happens to be using that version. The problem needs to be somehow specific to that version. Also, always use the "master" (in this case, [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs)), never just the version-specific tag. [From Cody Gray♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)
- Other [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs)-related tags that might be relevant include:

  - [tfsbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfsbuild) - for questions about "Automated Builds using the Team Foundation Server / Visual Studio Team Services build system"
  - [ms-release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-release-management) - for questions on Microsoft Release Management which is "a tool that allows you to automate the release and deployment cycle of software. It is part of Visual Studio / Team Foundation Server 2013 and beyond."
  - [tfs-web-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-web-access) - for questions on Team Foundation Server Web Access which is "a web interface to Microsoft Team Foundation Server project data."
  - [tfs-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-sdk) - for questions about the use of the Azure DevOps / TFS API, in any supported language, and any tools that support or build upon it.
  - [tfs-workitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-workitem) - for questions specifically about work items in TFS and Azure DevOps.

  When using these tools in the context of TFS again please include the master [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs) tag.
- Not all the untagged questions are for TFS. See e.g. [Facebook login is failing sometimes in iOS SDK 4.38.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983796)
- You can send posts that need handling to [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Don't flood the room though. There is a reason it says 6 to 8 weeks in the question.
- A mod (thanks Jon!) renamed [tfs2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2019) to [tfs-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-2019)
- If you find questions that you don't know how to re-tag, list them at the bottom of this answer or ask in the chatroom.

#### Left for the mods

This is one locked (and mod flagged) merge stub question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58840247/in-tfs-how-can-i-restrict-epic-or-feature-not-closed-until-related-child-featu

---

Needs an extra pair of eyes:

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480394/does-swc-support-babel-plugins (there seems to be no [swc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swc), I only added [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs))</s>

Comment: I checked [58506656](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506656/how-to-transform-gdf-time-domain-to-human-readable-time-intervals) question. Only applicable tag is `java`. Should I edit tags myself or there is some procedure I need to follow.

Comment: @talex you have full edit privileges,. feel free to make that edit / retag and then document your action in this answer.

Comment: Looks like someone already did it. I'll edit it out of this answer. I just wasn't sure, looks like you have some centralized process and I didn't wanted to stand in your way.

Comment: @talex this answer is the public facing part as is [the chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49974873#49974873) but it always surprises me that for these burnination type requests, the process *seems to happen magically*. I call this the "community process", it is not *my* process, or *my* effort. So you will never stand in my way. Thanks for checking and editing.