# Is a question tagged [untagged] an oxymoron?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The question [No question should be [untagged]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372558/no-question-should-be-untagged) indicated there were two questions (in 2018) so tagged and the answer implies it's a rarely used exception and that:

> The tag itself is blacklisted for all intents and purposes. You cannot add it to a question (only the system can), and **you cannot edit a question without replacing it.**

However, this small number of exceptions seems to no longer be the case.  There are currently 536 questions tagged [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).  The overwhelming majority are in the [WSO2 Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2).

Browsing the history of several of the questions involved, it seems that tags were added 2 days ago, but contrary to the claim that the tag must be replaced, it seems to survive as a second tag on hundreds of questions.

Was the retention of the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag a result of the command used to mass-tag several questions, or do the restrictions on the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag not apply to collectives, or is there some other obscure explanation for this paradox?

Comment: There was some retagging weirdness that happened Sunday and Monday and I'm guessing this is related.

Comment: There was [a mass tag renaming related to WSO2 a while ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418604/2821954).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the link. Seems "Community Managers will execute these changes, so there will be no work needed from the community." and that level of tag manipulation seems to have (probably by design) bypassed the restriction, so it probably just needs a (CM) cleanup.

Comment: They also recently [tweaked the merge/synonym code](/a/418662/15497888) which may or may not be related to whatever weirdness caused this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this! All WSO2 questions that were tagged with the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag have been cleaned up.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the report!

Through a series of unfortunate events, we had some issues with [the tag updates for WSO2-related tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418604/proposed-updates-to-wso2-tags). Some of the tags ended up being deleted and we had to re-add them to the questions that were supposed to have them. When a tag is deleted and there are no other tags on a question, the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) "tag" is added as a placeholder.

So, long story short - there is nothing special about Collectives when it comes to [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), and you're quite right in saying we have some cleanup to do. :)

I looked through the list of [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions and it seems like we have two separate issues there - the questions that also have a WSO2-related tag are clearly from this recent tag renaming, but questions that only have [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) on them ended up in that state some other way. We can at least clean up the WSO2 ones and then see what's left over.

I don't have an ETA for this, but hopefully soon™. In the meantime, if any of those questions needs to be edited for whatever reason, the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag can be safely removed at the same time.

Comment: For the non-WSO2 related stuff we can follow an approach similar to the one I started in 2020; [Can the untagged followers please attend to their tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399176/can-the-untagged-followers-please-attend-to-their-tag)

Comment: I can't believe that there wasn't any link associated with a "Series of Unfortunate Events" and that "soon" was used rather than 6 to 8 weeks.  I'm tempted to edit this answer. ;)