# Have these questions been [untagged] for so long?

Tags: bug, tags, 10k-tools

In the 10k tools, I found out about [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged):

[image]

The [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556228/any-post-or-get-requests-from-the-revue-api-return-401) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903986/justfile-unknown-start-of-token-in-an-exported-variable) tagged with it both seem to be created in January and had that tag since then. The ['New' tab on the tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) doesn't show [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Why is [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) shown as a new tag in the 10k tools now but all questions tagged with it are from January (and haven't been edited since January)?

Was there a bug allowing to ask questions without adding tags and [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) was just added to them without [the](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70556228/timeline) [timelines](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70903986/timeline) showing any event like that/no edit is visible?

It might also be worth retagging those two questions.

Comment: "Was there a bug allowing to ask questions" - no, it's an overflow tag from various tag manipulation. Might be the result of a tag being auto-removed, but I haven't seen that happen in practice, so I have my doubts as to whether it's enabled on SO. It's impossible for users or mods to tag stuff with untagged though. Untagged is regularly recreated by the system when a supported event occurs resulting in zero-tag questions; that's not a bug, that's the system doing its job

Comment: The events also don't leave a trace, which is a regular source of confusion and questions like these. The tags were somehow erased (I cannot tell you how because I have no way to find out without poking a CM, and it doesn't matter enough to justify that), which is done without a visible audit log. Similarly to merges, its a DB-level rewrite. It had a tag at some point, but some thing removed the tag on the DB level, resulting in it being [untagged], and looking like it was untagged at the time of being posted

Comment: I see. Does that mean those questions should be retagged?

Comment: Yep. If you see questions tagged [tag:untagged], you can retag them. They have to be retagged to be edited normally as well; the tag is blacklisted. The justfile one is tricky though, because it's a pain to make a tag for it that isn't ambiguous. Garbage name from an ambiguity perspective

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418733/is-a-question-tagged-untagged-an-oxymoron